# Backbone: Trouble with Collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to Login and then fetch list of items.

 From Login Model it tries to `reset` item list. Issue is when collection gets reset, Collection UI's doesn't catch it.

 
**Login Model's login function**

```
     login: function() {
        this.save(
            {}, {
                success: function(resp) {
                    var list = [];
                    list[0] = resp.get("0");
                    list[1] = resp.get("1");
                    dashboardList.reset(list);
                }
            });
       }
```

**DashboardList**

```
var DashboardList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: DashboardModel
});

var dashboardList= new DashboardList();
```

**Dashboard List View**

```
var DashboardListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },
    addOne: function(item) {
        var viewItem = new DashboardView({model: dashboardModel});
        this.$el.append(viewItem.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.addAll();
    }
});
```

**Dashboard Item View**

```
var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template('<div>'+
                        '<h3><%= campaignName %></h3>'+
                        '<span><%= orderedAndGoal %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= status %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= endDate %>, </span>'+
                        '</div>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        this.$el.appendTo('.container');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues:

1. Response from server was not as expected from collection. When I changed it some static data. It flow through.
2. Individual Dashboard View needs to return it's view object so that it can be rendered into the collection.

   `render: function() {
           console.log('what happens here')
           var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
           this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
           //this.$el.appendTo('.container');
           return this;
       },`